# How can we model Employee hierarchies (Software Engineer, Senior Software Engineer, Manager etc) along with their responsibilities?

Tags: java, database, oop, model

How can we best design class for structure where employee can have different Designation. Manager can manage few of employees. Every employee has some Responsibilities.
My thoughts were on the following lines. Would like to know better ways

```
enum DesignationLevel {
    SE, SSE, MANAGER;
}

class Designation {
    DesignationLevel dl;
    List responsibilies;
}

class Employee {
    Designation desig;
    Employee manager;
    List subordinates;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks okay. Don't use the raw type of `List`, use `List<Responsibility>` and `List<Employee>`.

Also what are `SE` and `SSE`? I can figure it out given the context of your question, but readers of your code may not be able to. Use proper names.

Also, how do you model a CEO, who has no manager - is it acceptable for manager to be null? Is there any situation where an employee may have more than one manager?

```
enum DesignationLevel {
    SOFTWARE_ENGINEER, SENIOR_SOFTWARE_ENGINEER, MANAGER;
}

class Designation {
    DesignationLevel designationLevel;
    List<Responsibility> responsibilities;
}

class Employee {
    Designation designation;
    Employee manager;
    List<Employee> subordinates;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Different designations as enum constants

```
enum Designation {
    SOFTWARE_ENGINEER, SENIOR_SOFTWARE_ENGINEER, MANAGER;
}
```

An Employee (General Employee as well as Manager) should have Designation and responsiblities based on their designation.

Also if an employee (i.e., manager) then he can have subordinates under him where they are also an employee, hence a List of type  is added.

As the subordinates is list of type , Manager can have subordinates and they can be employee or manager as well and Employee may not have subordinates.

```
class Employee {
    Designation designation;
    List<String> responsibilities;
    List<Employee> subordinates;
}
```

There can be separate class for those who are Directors and Management if required.